# How to add class to wp_nav_menu() function

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm developing my own custom Wordpress theme and I've got a problem while working on the menu navigations. Basically I have learned that Wordpress has function called `wp_nav_menu()` which contains this for example:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

But because I'm working with Foundation framework also, the menu tags has gotten some pre build classes. So my main menu looks like this:

```
<div class="top-bar" id="main-menu">
            <ul class="menu vertical medium-horizontal expanded medium-text-center" data-responsive-menu="drilldown medium-dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">Tech</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Energy</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Space</a>
                </li>
                <li ><a href="#">Medicine</a>
                </li>
                <li ><a href="#">Robotics</a>
                </li>
                <li ><a href="#">Tesla</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

So in order to install the `wp_nav_menu()` function here, I have to do this:

```
<div class="top-bar" id="main-menu">
            <?php 
                $args = array(
                    'theme_location' => 'top'
                );
            ?>
            <?php wp_nav_menu($args); ?>
        </div>
```

But the problem is because I have removed the class names and stylesheets from the menu elements ,the navigation will no loner be responsive !

So how can I add this Wordpress function to install the menu with the pre build classes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try and read the documentation for issues like this as the WordPress documentation is extensive and very good.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

To solve this issue, below `'theme_location' => 'top'` add in `'menu_class' => 'menu vertical medium-horizontal expanded medium-text-center'`. So your final code will be:

```
<div class="top-bar" id="main-menu">
        <?php 
            $args = array(
                'theme_location' => 'top',
                 'menu_class' => 'menu vertical medium-horizontal expanded medium-text-center'
            );
        ?>
        <?php wp_nav_menu($args); ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
 $args = array(
        'theme_location' => 'top'
        'menu_class' => 'menu vertical medium-horizontal expanded medium-text-center',        
    );
    wp_nav_menu( $args );
```

If you need data-responsive-menu too, you can add it with some js.

**Edit**

In $args, you can also use this

```
'items_wrap' => '<ul class="menu vertical medium-horizontal expanded medium-text-center" data-responsive-menu="drilldown medium-dropdown">%3$s</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu', 'menu_id3' => 'primary-menu3' ) );
```